# How to append multi-lines to file in a dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, centos7

I have a dockerfile and can't seem to be able to embed the nginx configuration file to it, so that it can be appended to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

I tried the following formats:

```
RUN cat <<EOT >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user                            www;
worker_processes                auto; # it will be determinate automatically by the number of core

error_log                       /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                             /var/run/nginx.pid; # it permit you to use /etc/init.d/nginx reload|restart|stop|start

events {
    worker_connections          1024;
}

http {
    include                     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type                application/octet-stream;
    sendfile                    on;
    access_log                  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    keepalive_timeout           3000;
    server {
        listen                  80;
        root                    /usr/local/www;
        index                   index.html index.htm;
        server_name             localhost;
        client_max_body_size    32m;
        error_page              500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root              /var/lib/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
EOT
```

and

```
RUN echo $
'user                            www; \n
worker_processes                auto; # it will be determinate automatically by the number of core \n

error_log                       /var/log/nginx/error.log warn; \n
pid                             /var/run/nginx.pid; # it permit you to use /etc/init.d/nginx reload|restart|stop|start \n

events { \n
    worker_connections          1024; \n
} \n

http { \n
    include                     /etc/nginx/mime.types; \n
    default_type                application/octet-stream; \n
    sendfile                    on; \n
    access_log                  /var/log/nginx/access.log; \n
    keepalive_timeout           3000; \n
    server { \n
        listen                  80; \n
        root                    /usr/local/www; \n
        index                   index.html index.htm; \n
        server_name             localhost; \n
        client_max_body_size    32m; \n
        error_page              500 502 503 504  /50x.html; \n
        location = /50x.html { \n
              root              /var/lib/nginx/html; \n
        } \n
    } \n
}' 
> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

However with either of the two examples I get the following error, which kinda looks like docker is trying to treat the nginx config file as its own variables:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 33.28 kB
Error response from daemon: Unknown instruction: WORKER_PROCESSES
```

Docker version is 1.13.1, build 07f3374/1.13.1 and the distro I am using is CentOS Atomic Host 7.1902, while docker base image is alpinelinux.

Thanks

Comment: But why? Wouldn't it be easier to put this in a file and `COPY` it?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with different line endings? I remember having issues with that, but I was on a windows machine.

Comment: But why? Perhaps you're pasting a Dockerfile into a Gist and you don't have the luxury of multiple files. Or perhaps you're working in a project that has a Dockerfile as an auxiliary feature and adding more files would pollute the root or require creation of a new directory to house the files. You can wget a Dockerfile, but you can't wget a Dockerfile and all of its files (without additional knowledge). Maybe you want to provide an example in documentation that illustrates a minimal solution; requiring multiple files complicates the description significantly.

Answer (score 20):

That should do the trick:

```
RUN echo $'first line \n\
second line \n\
third line' > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Basically it's wrapped in a `$''` and uses `\n\` for new lines.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to create & append lines to my `.npmrc` to install private packages. The only syntax that worked for me was:

```
RUN echo @myscope:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/ > .npmrc \
  && echo //gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=${MY_TOKEN} >> .npmrc \
  && echo strict-ssl=false >> .npmrc
```